# How to interpret this matplotlib's plot scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, visualization

The y-axis shows `1e-17+2e-4`.  not sure how to interpret this.

[image]

Comment: 1 is 1 * 1e-17 + 2e-4

Comment: Thanks @Stef , computing the numbers are making sense now!  I have two plots, the y-axis numbers are in the range `0.0001 - 0.0004` for my plots. But only for one plot it does this scale representation, for other plot it shows directly labels in this range `0.0001 - 0.0004` . any way to tell matplotlib to not do `1e-17 + 2e-4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a value of `y` equals `y * 1e-17 + 2e-4`

see [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):

> Offset notation and scientific notation
>
> Offset notation and scientific notation look quite similar at first
> sight. Both split some information from the formatted tick values and
> display it at the end of the axis.
>
> The scientific notation splits up the order of magnitude, i.e. a multiplicative scaling factor, e.g. 1e6.
>
> The offset notation separates an additive constant, e.g. +1e6. **The offset notation label is always prefixed with a + or - sign and is
> thus distinguishable from the order of magnitude label.**

You can control the usage of offsets with [`set_useOffset`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.set_useOffset):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, layout='constrained')
fig.suptitle('Both y-axes have equal scales:')

ax[0].set_ylim(.200001, .200010)

ax[1].set_ylim(.200001, .200010)
ax[1].yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

[image]